# How Do You Resolve Promises for Attributes of HTML Tags?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, promise, fetch

I'm trying to make a 'Favorite Albums' app using React, GraphQL, Apollo, MongoDB, and Express.
I'm having trouble implementing a feature that automatically grabs cover art from a localhost server that queries the MusicBrainz API. So far, the art-fetching aspect works perfectly: if I enter an artist + album combination, I get the cover art and that album is returned to the client side.

My ideal flow is this:

- When the app loads, get the albums data from MongoDB.
- If an album has a `thumbnail` property (a URL to the cover art),

  - use the thumbnail and display the image.
- Else,

  - go fetch the cover art.
  - Display the image once the promise is fulfilled.

The problem is, `getAlbumCover(album)` *always* returns a promise, as `async` functions seem to do. I'm just not sure what I have to do to make it return the URL from the fetch operation. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Below is the code for the `Album` component.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const Album = (props) => {

    const getAlbumCover = async (album) => {
        // Slugify text:
        function convertToSlug(Text) {
            return Text
                .toLowerCase()
                .replace(/ /g, '-')
                .replace(/\//g, '-')
                .replace(/[^\w-]+/g, '')
                ;
        }
        const artist = convertToSlug(album.artist.name);
        const name = convertToSlug(album.name);
        var result = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/album-art/${artist}/${name}`, {
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((result) => {
                return (<img id={`img-${album.id}`} src={result} />);
            })
    }
    
    const album = props.album;
    return (
        <div className="album-container">
            <img id={`img-${album.id}`} src={album.thumbnail ? album.thumbnail : getAlbumCover(album)} />
            <div className="album-header">
                <h3><em>{album.name}</em> <span className="details-yor">({album.yearOfRelease})</span></h3>
                <h3>- {album.artist.name}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Album;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cover needs to be retrieved, put it into state:

```
const Album = (props) => {
    const [cover, setCover] = useState('');
```

Get the cover, if needed, when the component mounts:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!props.album.thumbnail) {
        getAlbumCover();
    }
}, []);
```

```
// inside getAlbumCover:
.then(res => res.json())
.then(setCover)
.catch(handleError); // don't forget this; unhandled rejections should always be avoided
```

Then render it:

```
<img id={`img-${album.id}`} src={album.thumbnail || cover} />
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! That fixed it perfectly. I was attempting to useState multiple times but I kept getting errors with too many re-renders. I considered useEffect but did not know how I was to go about implementing it in this case. Again, thank you!